# How to avoid where query on associated models from getting fired twice(Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
Schema: User
id
name string(255)

Schema: Post
id
user_id
title string(255)
```

In controller I am querying `User` which has `has_many` relation with `Post`
This is what I do in the controller

```
@users = User.posts.where('title = ?','April Contest').group(:id)
```

Now in view file I am iterating through `@users`. For every `user` I need to fetch posts that satisfy title='April Contest'. For me to make this happen, it looks like I have to query again.

This is what I do in view:

```
@users.each do |user|
  A LOT OF  HTML THAT DISPLAYS DATA OF USER
 user.posts.where('title = ?','April Contest').each do |post|
    SOME HTML THAT DISPLAYS DATA OF POST
 end
end
```

Please help me avoid this `user.posts.where('title = ?','April Contest')` in the view file

Comment: you need `all modelA` objects. then for `each modelA` object you need corresponding `modelB` object that satisfies the where condition?

Comment: Very strange code. If `@modelA_objects = ModelA.modelbs...`, they are already `modelbs`. And than you iterate them , get `modelA_object`(that is modelb in that case) and trying to do modelA_object.modelbs... that is `ModelA.modelbs.modelbs`...

Comment: To clarify this, lets name `modelA == User`, `modelB == Post`. And you are naming  `@user_objects = User.posts.where...`?

Comment: @Nandhini Yes I need all modelA objects. then for each modelA object you need corresponding modelB object that satisfies the where condition

Comment: @YuriyVerbitskiy Yes I have updated the question too to users and posts, hopefully the question is easier to understand now

Comment: So its not ok to name collection of Post objects as @users

Comment: @Surya have posted my answer , try it out and let me know

Comment: @YuriyVerbitskiy yes it is not ok to name collection of post objects as users

Comment: @Nandhini Tried didn't work

Comment: `group(:id)` will throw the eager loading off. What it the purpose of the grouping?

Comment: @Swanand I am grouping because I am looping through users, I don't want to get the same user twice.

I have also tried without grouping, even there at view when 'user.posts' is called, a separate query is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

First get Users including the posts where title = 'April Contest'

```
@users = User.includes(:posts).where("posts.title = ?",'April Contest').references(:post)
```

Now in view you can iterate using `@users` and get the posts from `user.posts`

```
@users.each do |user|
  A LOT OF  HTML THAT DISPLAYS DATA OF USER
 user.posts.each do |post|
    SOME HTML THAT DISPLAYS DATA OF POST
 end
end
```

This avoid running the query again in view. Try this and let me know

Comment: No that doesn't help
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

References is of use when we use includes, it forces includes to fetch record in a single query.
In my case 'references' will not be of use.

Comment: what is the error that you are facing? `references` is to refer the included model's column in the where clause.

Comment: I am not facing any error. In view file when i am using `user.posts` it queries again

Comment: `user.pots` just iterates the `posts` associated with the `user` which was retrieved from the first query. The query will not be executed again, just the object is accessed. can you post the console log for the first query and the view?

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. 
Problem was I had a scope to `posts` and things got confused.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using [eager_load](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load)

```
@users = User.eager_load(:posts).where("posts.title = ?",'April Contest')
```

Eager_load loads all association in a single query using LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Now you will be able to access posts without an extra query

Comment: Thank you Rahul it worked, we also had a scope called `posts` and things got confused.